# Reduce function execution - Can anyone help me in identifying the error as I am unable get the result

Tags: javascript

```js
const sum = (arr) => {
  arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
    return acc = acc + val;
  }, 0);
};

console.log(sum([2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Have a look at [Arrow function expressions - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and how arrow functions work (how they return values).

Comment: why there is `br`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the result of the call to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in your `sum` method.

Also, in the `reduce` method you are returning the result of assigning a value. Returning the result of an assignment can be confusing and there is no need for that in this case.

Having all that in mind, your code should look:

```js
const sum = arr => arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);

console.log(sum([2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: _"you are returning the result of assigning a value"_ - which would be the result of `acc + val`

Comment: Yes, what I was trying to say is that returning the result of an assingment is confusing and there is no need for that in this case. I'll edit my answer to clarify.